# Correct parameter char *[] to call function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to implement bubble sort the function bubbleSort(names, size) and test it with my driver code. I get error on the driver code when I call the function. I would like to know how to set the first parameter correctly when I call the function.

I get two errors which is related to the first parameter "names".

> Error (active)    E0167   argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char **"
> Error   C2664   'void bubbleSort(char *[],const int)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char [8]' to 'char *[]'

I am using Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) with Visual Studio Community 2019.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

enum Bool { TRUE, FALSE };

void bubbleSort(char *names[], const int size)
{
    Bool swapped;
    char* temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        swapped = FALSE;
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (names[j] > names[j + 1])
            {
                temp = names[j];
                names[j] = names[j + 1];
                names[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = TRUE;
            }
        }
        // if no two elements were swapped by inner loop, then break
        if (swapped == FALSE)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char names[] = {'s', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'd', 'm', 'o'};
    int size = 8;
    bubbleSort(names, size);        // i get error here for 'names'
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << names[i] << " " << endl;
}
```

Comment: You declared the function to take a `char**` (same as `char*[]`) but you are passing in a `char*` (same as `char[]`) - just like the error already tells you by the way! Probably you should change your argument type to match what you are passing in!

Comment: @CherryDT I changed the parameter type from *names[] to names[] and local valuables in the function from *temp to temp and got rid of error, I was able to build and run.
Thank you so much for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sort function wants an array of C-strings, but you are passing it an array of characters. Hence the error.

To sort an array of characters, try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(char names[], const int size)
{
    bool swapped;
    char temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (names[j] > names[j + 1])
            {
                temp = names[j];
                names[j] = names[j + 1];
                names[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        // if no two elements were swapped by inner loop, then break
        if (!swapped)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char names[] = {'s', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'i', 'd', 'm', 'o'};
    int size = 8;
    bubbleSort(names, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << names[i] << " " << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, to sort an array of C-strings, try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void bubbleSort(const char* names[], const int size)
{
    bool swapped;
    const char* temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        swapped = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < size - i - 1; ++j)
        {
            if (strcmp(names[j], names[j + 1]) > 0)
            {
                temp = names[j];
                names[j] = names[j + 1];
                names[j + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
        // if no two elements were swapped by inner loop, then break
        if (!swapped)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const char* names[] = {"s", "a", "c", "d", "i", "d", "m", "o"};
    int size = 8;
    bubbleSort(names, size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << names[i] << " " << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I tried both of codes you suggested and they worked!